# Railway length with OSMNX

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am a total beginner with OSMNX, and I was wondering if (and how) I could get the length of an electrified railway that connects two specific cities, eg. Hambug and Hannover, in Python.
I am looking online, but I feel a little lost.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: There are two issues here: 1) how to use OSMnx, and 2) how to query Overpass for rail infrastructure. OSMnx's `custom_filter` argument in the `graph_from_place` function would be a good place to start. See the OSMnx usage examples for sample code to get started: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples If you provide a complete minimal reproducible code snippet of where you get to, it'll be easier to fill in any remaining gaps.